# Trying to load data from a txt file into a variable for requests

Tags: python, json

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
     dat2 = file.read()

post2 = {
        "id": 5,
        "method": "set",
        "params": [
            {
                "data": [
                     dat2
                    ],
                "url": "/config/url"
            },
            ]
        "session": sessionkey,
        "verbose": 1
        }
```

Data from the file I am trying to read looks as so...

`{"name": "Host1","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null},`
`{"name": "Host2","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null},` I am trying to read this data and insert into a variable to put it into `post2` for a request. What I have tried so far includes: reading the file and replacing `null` with `None` so python can read it as well as stripping all of the whitespace. I have tried using `json.loads()`, `json.load()` and `json.dumps()`, but nothing seems to work. When I try to use `json.load()` I get the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 18 (char 145)
```

After the data is placed into dat2, it gets inserted into post2 as '{data}' instead of {data}. Also yes, I know that `file.read()` will read the contents of the file into a string, but I have been trying everything since I am struggling to have success using json. I have been stuck on this part of my code for the longest time now and would appreciate and ideas. NOTE: I HAVE LOOKED AT MULTIPLE PYTHON/JSON POSTS FOR READING PYTHON AND NOTHING WORKS SO PLEASE DON'T MARK AS DUPLICATE.

Comment: Just a thought...I would try defining dat2 as a list by saying dat2 = file.readlines(). Then, in post2, the key "data" can be in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing apostrophe and put the dictionaries in a list in your file, it should look like this:

```
[{"name": "Host1","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null}, {"name": "Host2","type": "ipmask","subnet": ["0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255"],"dynamic_mapping": null}]
```

Then use `json.loads` to turn it into a list:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
     dat2 = file.read()

import json
post2 = {"data": json.loads(dat2)}
```

And this will make `post2` be

```
{'data': [{'name': 'Host1', 'type': 'ipmask', 'subnet': ['0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255'], 'dynamic_mapping': None}, {'name': 'Host2', 'type': 'ipmask', 'subnet': ['0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255'], 'dynamic_mapping': None}]}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Putting the dictionaries in a list gives the following when inserted into `post2` without json.loads(). When I try to use `json.loads()` or any other json loading i get errors .So it's inserting the single quotes and that's what I can't figure out

```{'data': ['{'name': 'Host1', 'type': 'ipmask', 'subnet': ['0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255'], 'dynamic_mapping': None},' '{'name': 'Host2', 'type': 'ipmask', 'subnet': ['0.0.0.0', '255.255.255.255'], 'dynamic_mapping': None}']}```